# Python Contour Plot irregular spaced data - Memory Error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a contour plot of non rectangular data without any interpolation (I do not want to use the meshgrid module here). Therefore I tried following code:

```
x_co=data_U[:,0] #-> 22450 rows
y_co=data_U[:,1] #-> 22450 rows
U_co=data_U[:,3] #-> 22450 rows
u_im=np.zeros((len(u_co),len(u_co))) #24450,22450 array
u_im[zip(y_co,x_co)]=U_co #22450,22450 array

fig1.plt.figure()
plate=pltcontourf(x_co,y_co,u_im,vmin=-10, vmax=10,extent=[x_co[0],x_co[-1],y_co[0],y_co[-1]],origin='upper',levels=level,cmap=plt.cm.jet,aspect='auto')   
plt.show
```

I do always run out of memory, so the idea is to decrease the resolution by np.meshgrid(xi,yi) with 1000,1000 points.
Next step would be interpolating data U_co on the new meshgrid, but the triangulation here connects vertices where it should not. So my non regular grid is not realistic given by the interpolation.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scipy.interpolate.griddata` to interpolate the data with the `method=nearest` ([see here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html)). Without the data it is difficult to help more but the code would look something like,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

x_co=data_U[:,0] #-> 22450 rows
y_co=data_U[:,1] #-> 22450 rows
U_co=data_U[:,3] #-> 22450 rows
interp_grid = np.meshgrid(1000,1000)
newgrid = griddata((x_co, y_co), U_co, interp_grid, method='linear')

plt.imshow(newgrid.T, origin='lower')
plt.show()
```

If you've got a uniform grid, I'd suggest using `imshow` instead of `contourf` as it should be faster.

Comment: Thanks, I know this method, the problem is that the interpolation with linear or nearest connects vertices which should not be connected. My mesh is not rectangular!

Comment: If `griddata` with `nearest` introduces too much connection for your case, maybe `cubic` would improve. There is also `map_coordinates` to reduce resolution using splines `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates`. I don't know if there is a general python tool to go from one grid to another without interpolation artefact. Maybe you need some form of adaptive mesh refinement type scheme, using `griddata` with `interp_grid` locally refined near complex features?

Comment: Otherwise, try `pcolorfast` with the original data or even `contourf` for parts of the domain and rasterize using `ax.set_rasterized` before plotting the next bit.